# Web server architecture for java rest json API

Tags: java, json, rest, jetty, restlet

I'm using this configuration for a high load Java JSON REST API:

- Jetty 6.1.26 with maven-jetty-plugin
- Java 1.7.0.5
- Restlet 2.0.13 as a RestFul framework
- Redis 2.4.14 as a database

Results with this are 1000 requests/sec per each server. 
Average answer size is around 1KB

Server is a EC2 Amazon instance:

```
High-CPU Extra Large Instance

7 GB of memory
20 EC2 Compute Units (8 virtual cores with 2.5 EC2 Compute Units each)
1690 GB of instance storage
64-bit platform
I/O Performance: High
API name: c1.xlarge
```

Some questions:

1. Are 1000 requests/sec OK?
2. Is there something you would change? Any techonology faster than Jetty for the web server, or Restlet? Maybe Jersey?
3. Any performance tip or special configuration for Jetty?

Comment: use a modern version of jetty, either jetty7 for servlet 2.5 support or jetty8 for servlet 3.0 support

Comment: I tried jetty 8 and got no changes on the requests per second. Thanks!

Comment: that tells me you need to re-evaluate your load testing, see this: http://webtide.intalio.com/2012/05/truth-in-benchmarking/ and http://webtide.intalio.com/2010/06/lies-damned-lies-and-benchmarks-2/

Comment: figured I would also mention that if you are looking to scale requests with servlets you need to look at async servlet, 1000 r/s is not particularly much depending on what your doing in the actual request processing, also this might not be the best forum for 'advice'

Comment: And where should I ask for advice?? I've looked for async requests but the problem is that I need to rewrite the whole app. If I got it right there's a static pool of threads that answer many requests and pass them to another pool of worker threads. Right now, each request knows what to do but it's own.

Comment: I don't know, I just know this: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions  though if you had asked this on the jetty mailing list you likely would have gotten a bit longer winded response, or our irc channel even.  I commented on here since there is no real _answer_ I could give you.

Comment: Ok thanks! I'll try those channels and hopefully come here with an answer!

Comment: I would consider bringing in http://jamonapi.sourceforge.net/ and measure, measure, measure. If you don't know where/what is time-consuming how can you give advice on update this or that component to a newer version. That's wild guessing.